# overriden bang (!) operator. Find sender

Tags: scala

When I override the bang (!) operator in Scala, it's invoked on the actor which is the recipient of the message. Is there a way I can find out who sent this msg to this actor inside the overridden bang operator?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see here how to override the behavior of the bang operator. In your particular case you can override it by wrapping the original message in an envelop containing the sender.

> > [How to override bang operator(!) for different type of inputs in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428419/how-to-override-bang-operator-for-different-type-of-inputs-in-scala/13429976#13429976)
> >
> > [How to overload bang(!) operator in Scala Actor model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371797/how-to-overload-bang-operator-in-scala-actor-model)

Also, please note that the Scala 2.9's actors API will become deprecated. Consider using [Akka](http://akka.io/) instead which does provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did check those threads. Actually I have a trait inherited from Actor and I am overriding my bang operator there. I would like to be able to get the sender at that point and not in the code where I am sending the message. Do you think it's possible to achieve this?

Comment: You can see this example to see how you can unwrap the message at the destination and get the sender: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395936/any-way-of-appending-to-the-act-method-in-scala/13398241#13398241. I hope I understood correctly.